# JavaScript clipboard doesn't work when I use the mouseover event

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. The JavaScript clipboard doesn't work when I use the mouseover event.If I use the click event, it works. I don't know how can solve this problem.

Code:

```js
function select(data) {
    var el = document.querySelector(data.el)
    var target = document.querySelector(data.target)

    el.addEventListener(data.event, function() {
        target.select();
        if(data.copy) {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy')
            
            console.log(successful)
        }
    }, false)
}

select({
    el: '.btn',
    event: 'mouseover',
    target: '[name="txtArea"]',
    copy: true
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Clipboard JS</title>
    <script src="js/clip.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="txtArea" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!">

<button class="btn">Select</button>

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `mouseover` event is not allowed to modify the clipboard.

The related links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandEnabled

https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#events-that-are-allowed-to-modify-the-clipboard

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#allowed-to-show-a-popup